# How do you make a div shaped like an ellipse in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the following shapes with css. I don't know how I can do this, can you help?

[image: ellipse divs]

Comment: @j08691 Why did you vote to close this?

Comment: @G-Cyr Why did you vote to close this?

Comment: @coreyward because it's a *give me a code* and not a question

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oy, you say that about everything. It's a perfectly valid question, especially because this is a relatively obscure area of HTML/CSS. And the question was closed as lacking focus, which is not at all the case here.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's true of most questions that you could find the answer by searching Google. This is true of many of your own questions. Take it from someone who has been here for 8 years longer than you: this comes up all the time. Thankfully, it is [not actually in the conditions for whether or not a question should be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-radius: 50%` and `transform: rotate(-10deg)` are what you're looking for.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #e1ecf4;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), but you will likely need to use a custom `path` rather than a simple shape since these are drawn off axis. Alternately, you may be able to get away with doing a `clip-path: ellipse(…)` and then `transform: rotate(…)` on the `div`, then another `transform: rotate(…)` with the opposite value on the contents to keep them aligned horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are the following:

1. First we have an ordinary, rectangular DIV (let it be 32px in this example):

```
#example {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

2. With the border-radius property, we effectively convert it to a circle. The trick is that if we give it a 16px border-radius, we get a circle:

```
#example {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

3. After that, with the `transform:` css-property we stretch it in a single direction. `transform: scaleX(...)` can stretch a div horizontally.

```
#example {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transform: scaleX(3.14);
}
```

And done.

To get a rotated ellipse, you need 2 divs, or a matrix-based css-transform, to combine rotation and stretching.